# Does compile time matter?

Tags: performance, compilation

Does compile time matter? How does the code affect the compile time?  Lastly, do comments in code affect the compile time?

Comment: I guess that depends on whether http://xkcd.com/303/ sounds appealing to you . . .

Comment: I used to work on a project where a full compile took 8 hours. If there were build errors in code from source control, that meant a full lost day for the entire team. I usually built the code once a week (at night). So compile time matters in that it should be as fast as possible.

Comment: How to ensure that the code will be fast compile as possible?

Comment: @Patrick: write less code.

Comment: @Mitch Like using methods/functions?

Comment: BTW: "I'm on my maybe halfway in learning programming " - you don't stop learning. Ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long compiles change how you think about working. If it costs you half an hour every time you change something, it makes you avoid changing things. This can actually be good: you end up thinking a lot more carefully since you can't experiment. Mostly though, it's a problem since it discourages trying new things.

Comment: "it makes you avoid changing things. This can actually be good:" - I suspect an agile worker would disagree. Change is inevitable. Embrace it. Do what ever you can to facilitate implementing change (fast CI, Unit Tests, Integration tests, UI Tests...)

Comment: Basically my point. The tendency of fast iteration to lead to changing things thoughtlessly is outweighed by the other benefits.

Answer (score 2):

Last first: comments don't affect compile time perceptibly; they're stripped off by the preprocessor before any of the actual work of compilation is commenced.

I wouldn't consider compile time an indicator of the quality of programming; the biggest thing that affects compile time is the actual size of the code (exclusive of comments, as previously noted).  Where compile time is an issue is that, first, it contributes to the weight gain and other health issues of programmers ("Compiling now, time for a soda."), and second, if extreme, it may contribute very slightly to the cost of a project, though I'd never expect it to be a huge issue unless recompiling for tiny changes in a huge project.

And this is one reason why large projects are universally handled as multiple, separately compiled modules; make a small change, and only compilation of the affected module and relinking are required, rather than a full build of the entire project.